# OpenCV floodFill() fills unconnected regions

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, flood-fill

I have implemented the connected component identification algorithm from [here](http://davidlavy.wordpress.com/opencv/connected-components-in-opencv/), but it seems, that the cv::floodFill(...) fills unconnected regions in some cases.

First of all, here is the code:

```
void ImageMatchingOpenCV::getConnectedComponents(const cv::Mat& binImg, vector<vector<cv::Point>>& components, vector<vector<cv::Point>>& contours, const int minSize)
  {
      cv::Mat ccImg;
      binImg.convertTo(ccImg, CV_32FC1);

      int gap=startPointParams.gap;
      int label = 1;
      for(int y=gap; y<binImg.rows-gap; ++y)
      {
          for(int x=gap; x<binImg.cols-gap; ++x)
          {
              if((int)ccImg.at<float>(y, x)!=255) continue;
              cv::Rect bBox;
              cv::floodFill(ccImg, cv::Point(x, y), cv::Scalar(label), &bBox, cv::Scalar(0), cv::Scalar(0), 4 /*| cv::FLOODFILL_FIXED_RANGE*/);
              if(bBox.x<gap || bBox.y<gap || bBox.x+bBox.width>=binImg.cols-gap || bBox.y+bBox.height>=binImg.rows-gap) continue;
              components.push_back(vector<cv::Point>()); contours.push_back(vector<cv::Point>());
              for(int i=bBox.y; i<bBox.y+bBox.height; ++i)
              {
                  for(int j=bBox.x; j<bBox.x+bBox.width; ++j)
                  {
                      if((int)ccImg.at<float>(i, j)!=label) continue;
                      components.back().push_back(cv::Point(j, i));
                      if(    (int)ccImg.at<float>(i+1, j)!=label
                          || (int)ccImg.at<float>(i-1, j)!=label
                          || (int)ccImg.at<float>(i, j+1)!=label
                          || (int)ccImg.at<float>(i, j-1)!=label) contours.back().push_back(cv::Point(j, i));
                  }
              }
              if(components.back().size()<minSize)
              {
                  components.pop_back();
                  contours.pop_back();
              }
              else
              {
                  ++label;
                  if(label==255) ++label;
                  break;
              }
          }
          if(label!=1) break;
      }       
  }
```

The input cv::Mat contains 2448x2050 pixels of size CV_8U. The pixel values are either 0 (background) or 255 (foreground). There are 17 connected components in the image. All components but the first are identified correctly. The erroneous component is by far largest one (~1.5 million pixels) and contains some small disconnected pixel-groups. It encompasses all of the other components. The small disconnected pixel-groups, which are wrongly assigned to the first component are all connected to the top of the components bounding box.

EDIT: I added some images to visualize the problem. The first image shows all identified connected components. The second image shows only the erroneous component (notice the small disconnected pixel groups at the top). The third images zooms a part of the second image:

[image: All components]

[image: The erroneous component]

[image: Zoomed erroneous component]

If someone has an idea, where the error might be, I would be thankful.

Comment: Attach the output image too, to understand better.

Comment: How are you choosing your starting point for flood fill? I'm trying to understand the loop there, it looks like you are looping over the entire binary image and picking a seed point that is on the contour?

Comment: Also as an aside, OpenCV does have a CC algorithm, it is buried in cv::findContours. You can use the general CC algorithm by using the  CV_RETR_CCOMP flag. They have a CC example here: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#drawcontours

Comment: @David Nilosek: The starting points are those, whose value is 255. The image is contains only the pixel values 0 and 255. The components have the value 255.

Comment: @David Nilosek: I already identified the connected components by applying cv::findContours(...) with the CV_RETR_CCOMP flag and calling cv::drawContours(...) afterwards. However, I need for each connected component a vector of all points, which belong to the component. With cv::drawContours(...) I get only labeled images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the bug myself. At the end of the method small components are thrown away. In this case the component's number (label) is not increased:

```
if(components.back().size()<minSize)
{
    components.pop_back();
    contours.pop_back();
}
else
{
    ++label;
    if(label==255) ++label;        
}
```

This means, the label number is used again to mark the next component in the image. Hence, several small components and a sufficiantly large component might have the same label number. If now the bounding box of the large component is iterated, then this bounding box might contain some small previously identified, but unused components with the same label number.

The solution is to remove the else branch and instead increase the label number always.